# PHP website Warning: require(/../core/database/connect.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

Hi I want to put my website(web application in PHP)  on a server of my school and it’s for a project for school. So I had read the instructions of my school where I had to put my source code. I had to put in a folder called ‘Html’ and according to my school that is used for php hosting. After putting my files in that folder I went to browse to my website.

But it doesn’t show me the website when I browse to it. Instead it had given me a error message, see link below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHVlq.jpg

After reading the error message I thought it had something to do with this line of code in connect.php file:

> mysql_connect('145.92.203.240', 'user', mypassword');

I thought that was looking fine, but I also tried “mysql_connect('localhost, 'user', mypassword');”, but I still receive the same error message.

Furthermore I had tried in “/etc/init.d” to restart apache. For this I used the following command:

> apache2 –k restart

But I couldn’t restart apache  because I don’t have permission.
I also had tried in “/var/www/localhost/htdocs” to show index.html on the browser. But that didn’t work as wel. I also couldn’t remove te index.html file and replace it with my source code.

Could someone please tell me the solution in steps?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text errors. Instead paste in the actual error.

Comment: Your script is trying to find the file `connect.php`, but can't find it in the location specified. If you have uploaded the application to a new server/location, then the directory structure is probably different...

Comment: I don't know if you copied the mysql_connect from your code. If you did, you are missing a ' before password. Also, can you post the connect.php code?

Comment: The error in your title is pretty clear - the file you're trying to `require` does NOT exist in the location you say it does, so PHP is doing what it's supposed to - aborting execution. This has **NOTHING** to do with mysql. It's purely a PHP and file path/location problem.

Comment: This is how my directory structure looks like:
http://i.imgur.com/BiZSYTq.png

I think this could maybe clear up more things.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here we go:

- You're trying to include a file and the location is wrong

For instance, `require('config.php');` will assume the file is in the same folder as the script. `require('./folder/config.php');` will assume the file is in the folder. So you may want to check exactly where connect.php is.

- The error about include_path

It seems as if you have a var `include_path` defined somewhere, might want to check that out. If you migrated it, you need to change the var to the new location.